# Selecting a row until the border

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I highlight a specific line by selecting the **row number**, I want the selection to **stop** at the border and not continue across the sheet.

Answer (score 3):

If you created an actual Excel Table object, then you could.

For example, this table:
[image]

Select any cell:
[image]

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will select the whole row in this table object:

[image]

Comment: If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer.

Comment: Great Excel hint. thanks ZygD! 
btw CTRL+Space select whole column in Excel Table, and CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE whole Table data, and finally double click CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE whole table with headers.

Comment: Nice keyboard shortcut. You can also hover the mouse over the left hand border of the table and get an arrow pointing to the right, then click to select the table row, much like doing this for a whole sheet row but with a slightly smaller target area for the mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no quick "row-with-data-only" selection with the **mouse** (like clicking on the row number). The keyboard shortcuts @ZygD provided works well for a table, but without it will still select the whole row/table. You can however try the following. Say your data runs A2 to F20 then, with the cursor in A2, pressing CTRL+SHIFT+right arrow (RA) will select the row until the first blank. If there is more data after a blank, just hit RA again while still holding CTRL+SHIFT.

Now to do multiple non-continuous row selections like this requires some dexterity. Press CTRL+SHIFT+RA to select one row. Let go of SHIFT and RA, but keep holding CTRL. Left click say cell A4. Hold down SHIFT again (and CTRL) and press RA. Left go SHIFT. Click with mouse say cell A7 (still holding CTRL). Hold SHIFT again and hit RA. Repeat until all relevant cells/rows have been selected.

Answer (score -1):

What you ask for is not possible